Movie about teens with magical powers
It's been at least 5 years since I started looking for this movie. I've actually never watched it, but I saw its trailer in the theaters at least twice.
I remember clearly that the movie was about "teenagers" with magical powers and there was a scene where they were wrong way driving a Jeep (or some car like a Jeep) and to avoid hitting a truck they dismantled their car while driving and remounted it after they passed the truck. Besides that I can remember that some old friend of them came back to the city and they were really worried about this guy who was stronger than they were.
I'm sorry for not having more info about it but I'll give a shot here, maybe somebody can help me.

And I would have thought of Chronicle (2012) since it have some similarities.


The Covenant (2006)

To the students of the Spenser Academy, the Sons of Ipswich, Caleb
  Danvers, Pogue Parry, Reid Garwin, and Tyler Simms, are the baddest
  boys on campus. But that's not all they share. The four friends also
  share a 300-year-old secret: they're warlocks, the teenage descendants
  of a 17th-century coven of witches....



Bound by their sacred ancestry and sworn to silence, these four teens
  share a secret so remarkable that it has served to protect their
  families for hundreds of years; they possess "The Power", a source of
  nearly limitless mystical abilities that drains their life force if it
  is used excessively. 



The battle is on to ensure the safety of The Covenant and lay the one
  descendent who threatens to reveal their secret to rest once and for
  all.


See the pic above? That's right before one of the "crash" sequences in the movie. Watch it here and the trailer here (or here).
~ Synopsis edited from Wikipedia

Thank you very VERY much! I really was looking forward to watch this movie but never found it. You just made my day =-)

Glad to help :-) It's actually a fun movie, with some neat SFX. Watch the Blu-ray... definitely worth it!

@Merurino I would just watch Chronicle, it is very similar and much better :)

@hmmmm Indeed, Chronicle is better than this movie. Not that this one is not a good movie, but Chronicle's plot was better though.
